# How to recover Bitcoin sent to example address on Bitcoin.org info page

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-qt-setup

Please,

I am very new and accidentally loaded funds into a sample wallet on the Bitcoin.org information site instead of my personal wallet.

This happened October 11, 2018.

Would you please help me.

Candace

Comment: Can you provide any more information like the address or how you loaded the funds

Comment: Absolutely I have screen shots of everything - how can I send you the screenshots

Comment: Welcome to this site. This is a question answer site meant to be a helpful reference, and not really a one-on-one help site. Anything you can needs to be in the question so it will be helpful for others in the future. If there is any sensitive information such as email address or private keys do not post it.

Comment: I have my buy crypto receipt and the address of the sample wallet from the bitcoin.org site.  So far I have been told to contact Bitcoin.org directly with no luck

Comment: where did you buy the bitcoin? And did you send it to the sample address?

Comment: Ok thanks - I loaded it at a ATM Bitcoin and loaded the funds to the following — 1AYPXMZYp5ZQvMv8cyVttjnTEONmbwCF2x

Comment: Completed Oct 11/18   10:49:48 Crypto 0.20768 BTC

Comment: Thank you so much for even responding.   I have been working at this for almost a month already.   I am obviously very new

Comment: This sample wallet is on the Coin Space Page of the Bitcoin.org information web site

Comment: @CandaceMcDonald: 1AYPXMZYp5ZQvMv8cyVttjnTEONmbwCF2x is not a valid address.  Are you sure you copied it correctly?  Also, did you get a transaction ID on your receipt?  (It would be 64 digits 0-9 and a-f).

Comment: It is a sample wallet on the Coin Space Page of Bitcoin.org site.   I thought I had downloaded a wallet and it turned out to just be a picture of a sample wallet

Comment: I’m sure the physical receipt is at home

Comment: @NateEldredge I think it is a valid address. I believe the TXID in question is ``e608ad0e1e0d562c8557e2e3b2008d08b0a29d5411bab3d198e25c495629c61e``

Comment: @KappaDev: Ah, they're slightly different.  Guess there were some typos.

Answer (score 2):

Your coins are gone.  Sorry.

As KappaDev found, the [transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/e608ad0e1e0d562c8557e2e3b2008d08b0a29d5411bab3d198e25c495629c61e) was confirmed, so it cannot be reversed.  The only way those coins can possibly be accessed now is by whoever generated that address, if they still have the private key.  It could have been someone working on the web page at bitcoin.org, or it could have been someone from coinspace who provided the image.  (I wasn't able to find any image on bitcoin.org with that address in it.)

However, you can see [here](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1AYPXMZYp5ZQvMv8cyVttjnTEoNmbwCF2X) that several other people sent coins to that address, as far back as 2016.  None of them have ever been spent.  So it's likely that whoever generated the address no longer has the private key, or never saved it in the first place, or at any rate has no intention of using it.  And even if they did, you would have no way to force them to give the coins back to you.